# Spring-boot test not working with code coverage but works without code coverage

Tags: junit4, spring-boot-test

I have a spring-boot service with spring-security, version -2.1.2.RELEASE. Java-11.0.2
I have test cases written for my API integration testing.
When I run my test cases without code coverage it works, but when I run it with code coverage it fails.
The exception is basically from a configuration file called WebSecurityConfig.java which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I have my ldap security check done here and also I am Auto Wiring a settings object called LdapSettings.java which is again a configuration.
Here is a glimpse of the exception which I get when I run with test with code coverage.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Nest member class_info_index 49 has bad constant type in class file com/acumenllc/notifications/config/security/WebSecurityConfig

Also please suggest me if I am doing anything wrong in the design here.